# Query from GraphQL to Sequelize.js SELECT ... WHERE COL1 = X AND (COL2 LIKE Y OR COL3 LIKE Y)

Tags: javascript, mysql, meteor, sequelize.js, graphql

I'm trying to figure out how to make a query with Sequelize.js that outputs something like

`SELECT ... WHERE C1 = X AND (C2 LIKE '%Y%' OR C3 LIKE '%Y%')... to MySQL`

code

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    findItems(_, args) {
      return Item.findAll({
        limit: 10,
        active: 1,
        offset: args.offset,
        order: [['created_at', 'DESC']],
        $or: [
          {
            column_a: {
              $like: args.y,
            },
          },
          {
            column_b: {
              $like: args.y,
            },
          }]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

It's querying `SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT...` (no where)

Schema from GraphQL

```
const typeDefinitions = `
        type Item {
                column_a: String,
                column_b: String,
                active: Int,
        }
        type Query {
                findItems(column_a: String, column_b: String, active: Int, offset: Int): [Item]
        }
        type Mutation {
                //..
        }
        schema {
                query: Query
                mutation: Mutation
}`;
export default [typeDefinitions];
```

The docs from Sequelize.js don't explain how to do this query, I don't know if the problem is coming from the GraphQL query either.

Here's the query

```
{
  findItems(column_a: "hello", column_b:"hello", active: 1, offset: 0) {
    column_a
    column_b
    active
    created_at
  }
}
```

`SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT...` (no where)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to put the $or inside the where and add a dollar sign.

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    findItems(_, args) {
      return Item.findAll({
        where: {
        active: 1,
        $or: [
          {
            column_a: {
              $like: args.y,
            },
          },
          {
            column_b: {
              $like: args.y,
            },
          }],
        },
        limit: 10,
        active: 1,
        offset: args.offset,
        order: [['created_at', 'DESC']],
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass in an optional where object to filter the query. See [Querying](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/)

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    findItems(_, args) {
      return Item.findAll({
        where: {
          column_a: args.x
        },
        limit: 10,
        active: 1,
        offset: args.offset,
        order: [['created_at', 'DESC']],
        $or: [
          {
            column_a: {
              $like: args.y,
            },
          },
          {
            column_b: {
              $like: args.y,
            },
          }]
      });
    }
  }
}
```